# Qt shows backtrace by exit

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

I am programming a minesweeper clone to get in touch with qt.
When I exit the Programm with the X on the right corner I get the following.

```
*** Error in `/home/.test/build-minesweeper-Desktop-Profile/minesweeper': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ffc01eba100 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x70bfb)[0x7fd2d0b93bfb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76fc6)[0x7fd2d0b99fc6]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7780e)[0x7fd2d0b9a80e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-   gnu/libQt5Core.so.5(_ZN14QObjectPrivate14deleteChildrenEv+0x71)[0x7fd2d1e96e11]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(_ZN7QWidgetD1Ev+0x36b)[0x7fd2d2792bdb]
/home/.test/build-minesweeper-Desktop-Profile/minesweeper(+0x4e2b)[0x55ef85688e2b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf1)[0x7fd2d0b432e1]
/home/.test/build-minesweeper-Desktop-Profile/minesweeper(+0x4f4a)[0x55ef85688f4a]
======= Memory map: ========
55ef85684000-55ef8568c000 r-xp 00000000 fe:05 335827230   /home/.test/build-minesweeper-Desktop-Profile/minesweeper
```

I did not include the complete output.

This is my main function.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton test;
    test.setText("test");

    QWidget mainWindow;
    QBoxLayout boxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom);
    QWidget mineWrapper;

    MineField layout;
    boxLayout.addWidget(&mineWrapper);
    boxLayout.addWidget(&test);

    mineWrapper.setLayout(&layout);
    mainWindow.setLayout(&boxLayout);

    mainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 600);
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();

}
```

If I remove the Boxlayout and only use MineField it works fine.

In practicly everthing works as aspected, if I would not get this output.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Calling `addWidget` changes the parent of the added widget. At the end of your `main` function, `mineWrapper` is destroyed first, and `boxLayout` will destroy its children (namely `mineWrapper`) again, causing a double-free error.

Comment: @Botje you are on to something, but not correct.

Comment: The actual problem is that you have child QObject allocated on the stack and the parent object will call _delete_ on children, and calling _delete_ with a stack address is undefined behavior. So allocate all the QObejct (except the mainWindow on the heap, that is how the framework is designed to work)

Comment: Thanks @Zlatomir this worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Zlatomir I have to allocate the QObjects on the heap instead of the stack.

The fixed code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton * test = new QPushButton;
    test->setText("test");

    QWidget mainWindow;
    QBoxLayout * boxLayout = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom);
    QWidget *mineWrapper = new QWidget;

    MineField *layout = new MineField;
    boxLayout->addWidget(mineWrapper);
    boxLayout->addWidget(test);

    mineWrapper->setLayout(layout);
    mainWindow.setLayout(boxLayout);

    mainWindow.setFixedSize(800, 600);
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();

}
```